# SSRS - Can Individual Columns in a Grouped Row be Hidden Without Hiding the Entire Row?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2014, aka Report Builder 3, to develop reports at work. The one I'm currently working on requires a "user-level view" and a "supervisor-level view". The difference between the views is that non-supervisory users don't need to see the first three columns and should only see data related to themselves, not other users. Supervisors ***do*** need to see everything, but also want to be able to limit what's on-screen at any given time.

I can read the user's role and set visibility based on that. The problem is that I can't hide the columns because the option is not available for them. The option ***IS*** available for the columns I'm not grouping on, so I assume that this is because the rows are being grouped on those first three columns. Is there a way around this?

[image: This is what it looks like in design view. I can't hide District because the option is not available.]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no nice way of doing this. You can actually hide columns that are not on the details rowgroup even though the right-click context menu does not show the option.

If you left click on the column head to select the entire row, then use the properties panel you can set the `Hidden` property to an expression.

[image]

In fact, what you are actually doing is setting all the textbox's hidden properties.
Unfortunately this literally just hides the textboxes so it just leaves a blank area. This might not be too bad if its at the start or end column but if it was in the middle there would be a gap.

In my sample report with the column not hidden
[image]

and then with it hidden
[image]

Sometimes you just have to rethink how you present the data. In my example, for instance, I could move the data I want to hide (Year) to the next column across but still in the same row group, then delete the first column. Like this...

[image]

Now when I run the report with everything visible it looks like this.

Now, I set the ROW visibility of the row with the [Year] field and when I run the report I get this...

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I was afraid of. So, back to the default option of having two different reports for two different audiences. Lame, but simple and effective.